# "An error occurred while creating the backup" in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to backup Magento files and database backup using System-> Tools -> Backups. Database backup is created fine, but when I try to backup the system files using "System Backup" , it throws an error and not creating backup. This is the error I am getting when I click "System Backup" button.

```
"An error occurred while creating the backup"
```

**In system.log**

```
2014-01-29T11:57:45+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 94
2014-01-29T11:57:45+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2014-01-29T11:57:45+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2014-01-29T11:57:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/public_html): failed to open dir: Permission denied
```

[image]

Comment: You should have an exception logged in `var/log`. This is the general error message for when the backup fails.

Comment: @Marius Yes, I checked in log. but the directory is empty. no errors logged.

Comment: Make sure the log is enabled.  There should be something in there because this line is above the message `Mage::log($e->getMessage());`

Comment: @Marius: error log is enabled in "developer" section already.

Comment: Damn...This is very strange indeed. I was sure that there should be an error message logged. I have no other ideas.

Comment: @Marius ok. I have added screenshot of error message in "System Backup".

Comment: I have re-uploaded all my magento files from local to live server. Now the error is logging. I have updated the error in post.

Comment: It looks like you don't have permissions to read or write on the disk

Comment: @Marius Thank you, But I couldn't find out, which folder needs write permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing exactly the same problem with you.

What I'm doing is changed the PEAR file permissions to 755 (public_html/lib/PEAR).

To change the PEAR file permissions, I need to go thru my File Manager on hosting cpanel.

I have no idea why i cannot change the PEAR file permissions thru FTP.

It give me "550 Could not change perms on PEAR: Permission denied".

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.